# Search not working. Appending a "<?" to the search

Tags: search

I entered this code in my footer widget, and the search box finally showed up:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div>
<input type=”text” value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
```

But when I run a search, a `<?` gets appended to the query, resulting in a page not found error. Even removing the `<?` doesn't bring me to a results page.

To me, the php code appears ok. I doublechecked and have searchform.php in the same folder as the rest of my page templates.

This is on http://dsiinfo.webfactional.com

I've done several searches and have spent a couple of hours and this but can't figure out what's causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really use `type=”text”` with curly quotes?

Comment: What's that: `action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">` ? Hint: The MarkUp colors does tell you if something is wrong.

Comment: I just copied and pasted, I don't know how they showed up as curly quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The form in your HTML code looks like this:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label class="hidden" for="s"><?php _e('Search this site:'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" value="Search site" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

PHp is not parsed in this fragment, so I guess you didn't include a PHP file, just regular HTML. Put the search form code in a PHP file.

You could for example add a function like this to your `functions.php`:

```
function t5_search_form( $args = array () )
{
    $defaults = array (
        'form_id'  => 'searchform',
        'name'     => 's',
        'charset'  => get_bloginfo( 'charset' ),
        'label'    => esc_attr__( 'Search', 't5_theme' ),
        'action'   => site_url(),
        'value'    => esc_attr(
            apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query( FALSE ) )
        ),
        'submit'   => esc_attr__( 'Search', 't5_theme' ),
        'template' => '
        <form role="search" id="%1$s" accept-charset="%2$s" action="%8$s">
        <label for="%3$s">%4$s</label>
        <input type="search" name="%3$s" id="%3$s" value="%5$s" aria-required="true" required%6$s>
        <input type="submit" value="%7$s">
        </form>',
        'print' => TRUE
    );

    $options = array_merge( $defaults, $args );
    $options = apply_filters( 't5_searchform', $options );
    extract( $options );
    $autofocus = ( is_search() and 0 === (int) $GLOBALS["wp_query"]->found_posts )
    ? ' autofocus' : '';

    $form = sprintf(
        $template,
        $form_id,
        $charset,
        $name,
        $label,
        $value,
        $autofocus,
        $submit,
        $action
    );

    $print and print $form;
    return $form;
}
```

… and call that function wherever you need it with `t5_search_form();`.

Also, don't use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`, use `echo home_url();` instead.

Comment: Hi toscho, thanks for the quick reply. I added your code to functions.php and tried t5_search_form(); 2 ways: embedded in php tags, eg <?php t5_search_form(); ?>, which doesn't show the search box on screen; and just putting t5_search_form(); in my search div in my footer text widget. That just outputs the text t5_search_form(); to the screen. I know i'm missing something very fundamental from my understanding.

Comment: @MMC Wait, you put the PHP code in a Widget in the backend? That cannot work, PHP is not allowed there.

Comment: I did, though when I removed it and inserted just the form code, the form displays in the footer. Any ideas? I'll keep researching in the meantime. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I'm looking into using z-index to have the search box floating on top of the center of the footer since PHP isn't allowed in there.